# Retrofit Observable Call() method Not set baseUrl and throw NP Exception

Tags: android, exception, retrofit, retrofit2

When call() method compile it doesn't set Endpoint url and throw NP Exception

```
        public Observable<ResultPojo> call() {
            final ResultPojo resultPojo;

            try {
                resultPojo = buildRestAdapter().registerSubDistributor
                        (subDistributorDetailModel.getRoleType(),
                                subDistributorDetailModel.getPassword(),
                                subDistributorDetailModel.getUserName(),
                                subDistributorDetailModel.getMobileNumber(),
                                subDistributorDetailModel.getAddress(),
                                subDistributorDetailModel.getFirmName(),
                                subDistributorDetailModel.getAge(),
                                subDistributorDetailModel.getFathersName());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw OnErrorThrowable.from(e);
            }
            return Observable.just(resultPojo);
        }
    });
}
```

"Method for Build RestAdapter and it Return apiManager Object"

```
private static SubDistributorApiManager buildRestAdapter(){

    Builder builder = new Builder()
            .setEndpoint(SubDistributorApiManager.BASE_URL);

    RestAdapter restAdapter = builder.build();
    SubDistributorApiManager apiManager = restAdapter.create(SubDistributorApiManager.class);


    return apiManager;
}
```

Comment: which version of Retrofit are you using? And also attach your ADB logs

Comment: com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0, this version i've used.